# How to get reflected runtime Method from AnyRef object?

Tags: scala, reflection

I am trying to get the reflected runtime method in an instance but it is not shown in the `decls` result:

```
val foo: AnyRef = new Object {
  def bar = 1
}
typeOf[foo.type].decls //Does not contain bar method
```

I tried to use Java reflection class and it works:

```
foo.getClass.getDeclaredMethods //It contains bar method
```

But I prefer to work with MethodSymbols and Scala Type than Java Class and Method reflection. How can I get the reflected MethodSymbol?

---

I want an method to look up an object passed as AnyRef for a method bar and call it. Something like below:

```
def getBarMethodFromObj(obj: AnyRef): MethodSymbol = {
  //typeOf(obj).decl(TermName("bar")) this doesn't work
}
```

I cannot use trait because bar can have different argument and return types and numbers. As Scala does not support varadic generic arguments, I plan to use reflection to find the method and call, but this cannot be done in Scala as well. I am currently use Java solution:

```
val bar = foo.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.find(_.getName == "bar")
bar.invoke(foo, params: _*)
```

However Java reflection does not retain generic types as it creates problem for List and Map, etc. So I want to know if I can implement this in Scala, or is there any coming solution

Comment: Note that `foo.bar` doesn't compile either. The value `foo` is of type `foo.type`, which is subtype of `AnyRef`, and `AnyRef` does not have a method `bar`. The `typeOf[foo.type]` gizmo contains only the information that can be inferred at compile time, and at compile time, there is nothing that indicates that `foo` has a method `bar`, from the compiler's perspective.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks for the comment. I changed to runtime reflected method

Comment: TypeTags are sufficient for most use cases, I would think, but what is your use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but removing the `AnyRef` annotation makes your code work:

```
val foo = new { def bar = 1 }
typeOf[foo.type].decls // Contains bar method
```

If you need a type annotation (for example, in a method signature), you can use the same structural type that the compiler infers:

```
val foo: { def bar: Int } = new { def bar = 1 }
```

If you want to get the full list of methods from another method without knowing the exact type except via generics, you may be interested in `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ TypeTag, typeTag }
val foo = new { def bar = 1 }
def getMethods[T: TypeTag](t: T) = typeTag[T].tpe.decls
getMethods(foo) // Contains bar
```

If you can't use `TypeTag` (maybe because you can't make API changes), then you're probably best off using the Java reflection API. The Scala reflection API is generally designed to use type information, so it may not work for you if you only know the type is `AnyRef`.

---

In response to your edit:

> I cannot use trait because bar can have different argument and return types and numbers.

Sure you can:

```
trait Foo[A, B] {
  def bar(a: A): B
}
```

If you need multiple arguments, just have `bar` take a tuple instead. If you need to do some list manipulation that tuples don't support, you might consider learning about HLists and [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

> However Java reflection does not retain generic types...

Well, no runtime-only reflection API will help you there. There is simply no way to find out what generic parameters an `AnyRef` has at runtime, as that information doesn't exist on the JVM. Use TypeTags, or use a `trait` in the manner described above.

Comment: In your exampl3, foo is not AnyRef, but an Anonymous class with bar method declared so you can use decls. In my use case, foo is passed from a parameter with no known type but AnyRef so decls won't work

Comment: @texasbruce I figured that. I suggest changing your API to use TypeTags or structural types instead. Otherwise, I think you're stuck with the Java reflection API.

Comment: @texasbruce I've updated my answer to respond to your edit.

Comment: It doesn't actually fit my need, as the method I want has undefined number of parameters (variadic parameters), but Scala does not support generic var args so I wanted to resort to using reflection. But I also need to retain the generic parameter when the parameter is like List[Foo]. I guess this is impossible task for Scala current version now. I accepted this answer because it mentioned that it is impossible.